# Scatterplot with restrictions using an 'if' statement

Tags: r, plot

I am stuck trying on this plotting, and I hope you can help.

I currently have the matrix:

```
hello <- matrix(0:2, nrow=30, ncol=30)
```

I would like to plot points from x and y only when hello==1

```
x <- sample(5:25, 25,replace=TRUE)
y <- sample(5:25, 25,replace=TRUE)
```

I am currently trying to use an 'if' statement to restrict the plotting area, and am so far unsuccessful. As you can see if you plot it, the points are still randomly distributed.

My code is below:

```
hello <- matrix(0:1, nrow=30, ncol=30)
    if (hello[i,j]==1)
    {
      x <- sample(5:25, 25,replace=TRUE) 
      y <- sample(5:25, 25,replace=TRUE)
    }
    plot(1:30, 1:30, type="n")
    image(1:nrow(hello), 1:ncol(hello), hello, col=c("white", "yellow"))
      #visualize 1 and 0s
    points(x,y, col="green")
  }
}
```

*edit: got rid of the for loop

Comment: What is the point of your `for` loops? There is nothing inside them that is indexed by `i` or `j`. Each time you pass through the loop & call `plot()`, the previous plot would be overwritten.

Comment: @gung , that's my fault, I was not thinking. I'm still clumsy with R and I added that in out of habit.

Comment: your code does not work and it is very very hard to understand what you want to achive

Comment: @marvin_dpr, I apologize for that. I know it doesn't work, and that's why I need help.

Comment: no, I mean it does not work because there are object undefined within the example: ``i`` and ``j`` within ``if (hello[i,j]==1)``, also the last two curly braces are have no opening counterparts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had a very hard time to figure out what you want to do:

Supposing ... :

- ... you have a grid saved in hello that stores information of valid points for plotting (hello[1,2] stores the information for valid plotting of coordinate x=2 and y=1)
- ... possible candidates for plotting are pairs of x and y

... than this might be the answer, try it out:

```
# gen data
x <- 1:30
y <- 1:30
hello <- matrix(0:1, nrow=30, ncol=30)

# make basic plot of hello matrix
image(  1:ncol(hello), 1:nrow(hello), 
        t(hello), col=ifelse(t(hello)==1,"yellow","white"),
        ylab="rows",xlab="columns"      )
box()

# now let's decide whether or not a coordinate should be plotted, 
# depending on the value of hello for this coordinate ...
# by cycling through each pair of coordinates and saving T/F in iffer
iffer <- NULL
for(i in seq_along(x)) iffer <- c( iffer, hello[ y[i] , x[i] ]==1 )

# plotting of the adequate subset of points that had a hello value of 1 
points( x[iffer] , y[iffer], col="green")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I had hoped to get. Thank you! Do you mind letting me know what I should have said to phrase my question so it's easier to understand? It made sense to me, but that's obviously not the case when I tried to explain it.

Comment: @Mengll ... hmmm, I would have probably written something like: I have coordinates (x,y) that should only be plotted when in specific areas, areas for plotting are stored in a matrix (hello), ... but than its always easier to formulate a question when you know the answer - right.

Comment: alright. I'll try word things better next time. Thanks again!